# Calculate Field Date

Tags: arcgis-pro, field-calculator, date

So I created a `Date` field in a dataset with `5 rows` and so I then right clicked on `Calculate Field` to enter the date (all 5 rows have the same date). The date I entered was `1/1/2022` but `Pro` did not like the format and entered the date as `1899 something something with some time`.

The dataset is a `feature class` stored in a local geodatabase.

So how can I like enter the date value in the correct format in ArcGIS Pro 3.1 ?

Comment: The ISO format for date entry is YYYY-MM-DD. Please [Edit] the question to indicate the storage format for your table (shapefile, FGDB, EGDB), since the formatting can be different for each provider.

Comment: Suggest you upgrade to 3.2, they have a new [date only](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/data/geodatabases/overview/arcgis-field-data-types.htm#GUID-6F9BA736-430A-4CBD-990A-AA4C5E91FAB6) data type specifically for this issue.

Comment: @Hornbydd oh I see, cheers for pointing that out so is `date only` like different from the regular `date data type` as the latter contains both date and time.

Comment: @Vince yeah so you know when you double click on the field in the attribute table a `calendar` icon appears for the user to select a date. So on that calendar I selected January 1st 2022 instead of typing in the date. So once I entered the date it showed up as `1/1/2022` so I thought okay that might be the format that I am suppose to use in calculate field but I guess that's not the case. As when I entered `1/1/2022` in the `Field Calculator `Pro` did not recognize it and instead entered the date as `1899 something with some time`

Comment: Simply put your date in quotes, `"1/1/2022"`, and ArcGIS Pro will parse the string representation of a date to a datetime object and insert it into the Date ArcGIS field.  In an ArcGIS Date field, which is really a date and time combination field, if you only want to see the date and not a date and time, set the time to `00:00` and it won't display when viewing in a table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easier way might be using the Attributes pane.

You access the Attributes pane via the Edit tab in the Selection group by clicking the button labeled "Attributes". That will open the pane shown below, this pane is divided into a tree view on top and an attributes view on the bottom.

The attributes pane in its default state only shows attributes for the selected features. You can select the individual features in the tree view and update attributes in the attributes view. In your case, you would select the layer name at the top of the tree view, then enter your values in the appropriate field in the attributes view - this will update that field's value for all of the selected features. If you're entering dates, you can also use the calendar picker tool when the field is activated.

I have created [a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rJBf_zyxedQ) showing some of the uses of the attributes pane.

[image]

Comment: Can you please expand to how to access `Attributes pane` and `select the layer name in the tree view` in your answer?

Comment: Just updated the answer to be more clear on how to access and use the attributes pane.

Answer (score 2):

So, it turns out that I was not using the `datetime` function in the field calculator. Hence, when I typed `datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 11)`, Pro was able to pick the correct date that is `1/11/2022`.

Comment: As I mentioned in my comment to your original question, you can simply quote your date value to have it parsed correctly as a datetime object.

Answer (score 0):

**Settings on your Windows system determine how the dates display in ArcGIS Pro—M/d/yy, MM/dd/yy, yy/MM/dd, and so on.**

My system date is dd/MM/yyyy, and the field calculator accepts all possible short-form dates (inside personal geodatabase).

Comment: Oh I see so I had to type in the date as `01/01/2022` instead of `1/1/2022`?

Comment: On my PC it works with both, however, keep in mind the Regional Format. I'm using English (United Kingdom) so the default format is dd/MM/yyyy, if I type 02/23/2022 it will swap 23 with 02 to fit my PC format.